# iterate on hash of hashes to save nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a hash of hashes that I obtain from the params. Looking like this:

```
{"0"=>{"product_attribute_id"=>"4"}, "1"=>{"product_attribute_id"=>"7"}}
```

now essentially what I want to do is something like this:

```
  class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_product(product_id, instruction, attributes)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id, instruction: instruction)
      attributes.each do |key, value|
        current_item.line_item_attributes.build(product_attribute_id: value['product_attribute_id'])
      end
    end
    current_item
  end
```

but for some reason this doesn't seem to work

Comment: What is `current_item`? That line of code in your loop runs multiple times, so it's only effectively using the `value` from the last iteration, is that your intent?

Comment: @SunilD. I've updated my answer to include the entire code bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just fyi, assuming you are using the Rails' `build` method used in active model associations, `build` will not *save* to database.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html
It reads:

> build_association(attributes = {}) Returns a new object of the
>   associated type that has been instantiated with attributes and linked
>   to this object through a foreign key, but has not yet been saved.

Comment: hmm, I don't entirely see what it does then. It seems to work on the current_item variable that I have.